# What has caused my pocket door to be stuck?

Tags: pocket-door

I just got a new (to me) home and it has a pocket door stuck closed. It is a little slanted with the top of the pocket door a 1/2 inch recessed from the door stop trim while the bottom of the door protrudes 1/4 inch. When trying to open, it appears to rock at the front rollers but I can't see anything to be wrong. I've pulled a good deal with no effect. Does anyone have an idea as to what has gone wrong and ideas on how to fix it? Here's a picture of what the front roller/carriage (whatever it is called) looks like:

[image]

There is a wheel on both sides of it and it almost seems as though the wheels are locked against the wall because the entire door rotates slightly at that location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the door and frame. I'm guessing it's a new home for you but not a newly built home so you'll have to fix this yourself. Rollers go bad. They are usually plastic and have bearing and they will eventually wear out moving that heavy door back and forth for years. When that happens, you need to change the roller assembly. Pictured below is an assembly that looks similar to what you've got from Amazon. You've got to remove the door from the rollers, slide the rollers off the track, slide the new ones back and re attach the door.

[image]

Comment: Note that in @jack's picture, there is a lever between the plate and the rollers. Moving that aside releases the plate (and thus the door) from the roller.

Answer (score 1):

Try applying varying degrees of pressure with your foot on the bottom of the door, while you pull steadily on the top.

Comment: I've tried pulling the handle while pushing with my foot and it hasn't budged, I'm not sure I can get much grip on the top

Answer (score 1):

Make sure pictures aren't hung on the pocket into the door. I've also seen baseboard nailed to the door in the pocket.

Answer (score 0):

It is out of the rails on the top.

Normally you would lift the door and take it out of the rails on the top.

Then either replace worn out casters or use the adjustment screws on them to make the door hanging leveled.

Use screwdriver as aid and lift it to put it in the rails.

Answer (score -1):

Since it is a new home it should have a warranty, exercise this and have the builder repair it. By trying to fix it you could void the warranty. It will only take a phone call. While you are at it check everything else in the home you can just to be sure this is the only thing that has problems.

When we purchased our 20 year old home it had a 1 year warranty. That can vary from stat to state. Apparently you did not get one.

Comment: I should have been more clear, the home is new to me but 30 years old.